# conda install in jupyter notebooks stopped when forgetting "-y"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

It unfortunately happens that I forget to put the "-y" when I install a conda module (e.g. `!conda install pandas`) from a jupyter notebook.

When I do this, the text of the dialog of the command line is reproduced in the output of the running cell but (to my knowledge) I can't give an answer (i.e "y") and the notebook gets blocked (I can't execute any cells anymore).

Is there a way to "free up" Jupyter *without restarting the kernel* when this happens?

Comment: Click the "stop" button, or restart the kernel

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: You can check if the command terminal that runs the server is waiting for an input.  You can type `y` and Enter if it is.